# To model an unknown bounded probability density function by a Gaussian mixture

Tags: distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, bounds

I have points in dimension 10 coming from an unknown probability distribution. The nature of data strongly suggests that this distribution is bounded. But the boundaries are not precisely known and are estimated from the data.

However, due to the quite high dimension of the points, I chose to model the distribution with a Gaussian mixture. Then, the Gaussian mixture distribution is truncated to respect the boundaries.

- Do you think this methodology is a good idea?
- Do you have ideas of ways to directly model the unknown distribution by a bounded one?

Comment: If you do not know the boundaries, how can you use a truncated Guassian mixture?

Comment: I estimate their values from the data I have got.